# Group word based on length using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I would like to group the data based on the length using `pyspark`.

```
a= sc.parallelize(("number","algebra","int","str","raj"))
```

Expected output is in the form

```
(("int","str","raj"),("number"),("algebra"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= sc.parallelize(("number","algebra","int","str","raj"))
a.collect()
    ['number', 'algebra', 'int', 'str', 'raj']
```

Now, do the following steps to get the final output -

```
# Creating a tuple of the length of the word and the word itself.
a = a.map(lambda x:(len(x),x))

# Grouping by key (which is length of tuple)
a = a.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:list(x)).map(lambda x:x[1])
a.collect()
    [['int', 'str', 'raj'], ['number'], ['algebra']]
```